# Using a rolling time interval to count rows in R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataframe of timestamps with the corresponding number of tickets sold at that time.

```
         Timestamp          ticket_count
            (time)              (int)
1  2016-01-01 05:30:00            1
2  2016-01-01 05:32:00            1
3  2016-01-01 05:38:00            1
4  2016-01-01 05:46:00            1
5  2016-01-01 05:47:00            1
6  2016-01-01 06:07:00            1
7  2016-01-01 06:13:00            2
8  2016-01-01 06:21:00            1
9  2016-01-01 06:22:00            1
10 2016-01-01 06:25:00            1
```

I want to know how to calculate the number of tickets sold within a certain time frame of all tickets. For example, I want to calculate the number of tickets sold up to 15 minutes after all tickets. In this case, the first row would have three tickets, the second row would have four tickets, etc.

Ideally, I'm looking for a dplyr solution, as I want to do this for multiple stores with a `group_by()` function. However, I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to hold each Timestamp fixed for a given row while simultaneously searching through all Timestamps via dplyr syntax.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simpler version of the ugly one I wrote earlier..

```
# install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'),
         ticket_count = as.numeric(ticket_count)) %>%
  mutate(window = cut(timestamp, '15 min')) %>%
  group_by(window) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(tickets = sum(ticket_count))

               window tickets
               (fctr)   (dbl)
1 2016-01-01 05:30:00       3
2 2016-01-01 05:45:00       2
3 2016-01-01 06:00:00       3
4 2016-01-01 06:15:00       3
```

Answer (score 4):

In the [current development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table`, v1.9.7, `non-equi` joins are implemented. Assuming your `data.frame` is called `df` and the `Timestamp` column is `POSIXct` type:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
window = 15L # minutes
(counts = setDT(df)[.(t=Timestamp+window*60L), on=.(Timestamp<t), 
                     .(counts=sum(ticket_count)), by=.EACHI]$counts)
#  [1]  3  4  5  5  5  9 11 11 11 11

# add that as a column to original data.table by reference
df[, counts := counts]
```

For each row in `t`, all rows where `df$Timestamp < that_row` is fetched. And `by=.EACHI` instructs the expression `sum(ticket_count)` to run for each row in `t`. That gives your desired result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using data.table. Also incorporating different stores.

Example data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Timestamp = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 05:30:00")+seq(60,120000,by=60),
                 ticket_count = sample(1:9, 2000, T),
                 store = c(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 500)))
```

Now apply the following:

```
ts <- dt$Timestamp
for(x in ts) {
  end <- x+900
  dt[Timestamp <= end & Timestamp >= x ,CS := sum(ticket_count),by=store]
}
```

This gives you

```
                    Timestamp ticket_count store CS
       1: 2016-01-01 05:31:00            3     A 13
       2: 2016-01-01 05:32:00            5     B 20
       3: 2016-01-01 05:33:00            3     C 19
       4: 2016-01-01 05:34:00            7     D 12
       5: 2016-01-01 05:35:00            1     A 15
      ---                                          
    1996: 2016-01-02 14:46:00            4     D 10
    1997: 2016-01-02 14:47:00            9     A  9
    1998: 2016-01-02 14:48:00            2     B  2
    1999: 2016-01-02 14:49:00            2     C  2
    2000: 2016-01-02 14:50:00            6     D  6
```

Comment: Not quite. This would be the correct answer for the second row only. The window each row needs is different. So for the first row, I want to know the number of tickets between 5:30 and 5:45, the second row would be the number of tickets between 5:32 and 5:47, the third row between 5:38 and 5:53, etc. Does this make sense?